# Three js angular: Property 'dispose' does not exist on type 'Material | Material[]'

Tags: angular, types, three.js

I have a angular 6.0.5 running three.

All was working with three version 0.89.0 and @types/three version 0.84.3

I have updated to three version 0.93.0 and @types/three version 0.92.5

and everything is now broken. I get the following errors:

```
Property 'dispose' does not exist on type 'Material | Material[]'.

Property 'dispose' does not exist on type 'Material[]'.
```

and

```
Property 'clippingPlanes' does not exist on type 'Material | 
Material[]'.
Property 'clippingPlanes' does not exist on type 'Material[]'.
```

and

```
Property 'clippingPlanes' does not exist on type 'Material | 
Material[]'.

Property 'clippingPlanes' does not exist on type 'Material[]'.
```

and

```
Argument of type '{ shading: Shading; side: Side; shininess: number; 
color: number; transparent: true; opacity: num...' is not assignable 
to parameter of type 'MeshPhongMaterialParameters'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'shading' does 
not exist in type 'MeshPhongMaterialParameters'.
```

my guess is that types and library are not compatible. Does anybody know how to fix this mess?

Comment: Are you using a multi-material? If so, you should perform `dispose` on each material in the array, not on the array itself.

Comment: I am calling dispose in each material. That's not the problem, it looks more like incompatibility between latest npm version of three and latest npm version of @types/three. I need to know the latest npm versions of three and @types/three that are compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've hit this problem too. It's because there is no Multimaterial, you have to use a material array. If you look at the signature of "material" in Mesh, it is now:
Material | Material[]
so you can't access it as a material directly. What I did, and assuming you don't ever use a material array, is cast to , so for example:

```
mesh1.material.dispose();  //error since material could be an array
(<any>mesh1.material).dispose();     //OK since it doesn't know what it is
```

I suppose the general solution is to check for an array and handle each case separately, but that would make for ugly code, so maybe there is a better solution.

Your other problem is that "shading" has changed to a boolean "flatShading".

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can write a function with a typeguard to check whether `mesh.material` is an instance of `THREE.Material` and dispose of the mesh:

```
function disposeMesh(mesh: THREE.Mesh) {
  if (mesh.material instanceof Material) {
    mesh.material.dispose()
  } else if (Array.isArray(mesh.material)) {
    for (const material of mesh.material) {
      material.dispose()
    }
  }

  mesh.geometry.dispose()
}
```